Reproduce band structure Kagome fermi-hubbard - Python
I am trying to reproduce figure 5c) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.03116.pdf in Python.
So I would like to plot the band structure of a Fermi-hubbard defined in a Kagome lattice.
The eigenvalues are:
$\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}} / t = 2,-1 \pm \sqrt{3+2 \sum_{\nu=1}^3 \cos \left(\boldsymbol{k}\cdot  e_{\nu}\right)}$
and we defined a high symmetry point path in the Brillouin zone: Gamma-K-M-Gamma
My attempt:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# lattice vectors
a1 = np.array([1, 0])
a2 = np.array([-1/2, np.sqrt(3)/2])
a3 = -(a1 + a2)
a = [a1,a2,a3]

#high symmetry points
Gamma = np.array([0, 0])
K = 2*np.pi*np.array([2/3, 0])
M = 2*np.pi*np.array([0, 1/np.sqrt(3)])


num_points = 100
k_path = np.concatenate([np.linspace(k_Gamma, k_K, num_points, endpoint=False),
                         np.linspace(k_K, k_M, num_points, endpoint=False),
                         np.linspace(k_M, k_Gamma, num_points)])


# Calculate energy eigenvalues for each k-point
energies = np.zeros((3, len(k_path)))
for i, k in enumerate(k_path):
    cos_sum = np.cos(np.dot(k,a[0]))+ np.cos(np.dot(k,a[1]))+np.cos(np.dot(k,a[2]))
    energies[:, i] = [2, -1 + np.sqrt(3 + 2*cos_sum), -1 - np.sqrt(3 + 2*cos_sum)]

    
    
# Plot the energy bands
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
for band in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(k_path)), energies[band], label=f'Band {band+1}')

plt.ylabel('Energy')

plt.grid(True)

plt.xticks([0, 3*num_points//3, 2*3*num_points//3, num_points*3], [r'$\Gamma$', 'K', 'M', r'$\Gamma$'])




You haven't actually asked a question! If it's about errors in the code, that's off-topic here. If it's about interpreting the output, include that in the post (like including figures).

ok thanks! Indeed it's about my errors in the code because i cannot reproduce the figure. i will look for another section/forum where to post it
